# Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm try to return true from my getData method to be redirected after login to the homepage by $_SESSION['username'] but I'm always getting the error above. How can I make this method to work to return true?

```php
<?php

class Login
{
    private $host        = "localhost";
    private $user        = "root";
    private $db_password = "*****";
    private $database    = "*******";

    private $db;

    private $username;
    private $password;

    function __construct($username, $password)
    {
        // Set data
        $this->setData($username, $password);

        // connect to db
        $this->connectToDb();

        //get Data
        $this->getData();

    }

   private function setData($username, $password){

             $this->username = $username;
             $this->password = $password;

            }

    private function connectToDb(){
                      // connect to the server.
                   $this->db = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->db_password);    
                       if ($this->db->connect_errno) {
                           die("We are sorry, you could not be connected to the server,
                            plaese check your connection setting!");
                       }else{
                           echo "You are connected to the database";
                       }


            }

       private function getData(){
                $query ="SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$this->username' AND
                                                    password = '$this->password'";

                $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);  
                $stmt->bind_param('ss', $this->username, $this->passowrd); //Hier is the error.
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->bind_result($username, $password);
                $stmt->fetch();
                $numberofrows = $stmt->num_rows();

                echo  '# rows: '.$numberofrows;

                if ($numberofrows>1) {
                     return true;
                }else{
                    throw new Exception("Please check your username and passowrd!");

                }

             }
        }
?>
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Your `prepare()` is failing because you are not using `?` placeholders. You should not have the variables `$this->username, $this->password` in the SQL string. Replace those with `?` (unquoted) placeholders and everything else looks ok.

Comment: shouldn't it be $numberofrows>=1

Comment: `WHERE username = ? AND password = ?`  (by the way, this suggests you are storing passwords in plain text, which is really unsafe. I suggest reviewing [this question and its anwsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php) for modern solutions to password storage & hashing)

Comment: I changed the variables  with ? placeholder but I'm still getting this error. I will read your link

Comment: Always check the return value from `prepare()` and `execute()`. They return **false** if there's a problem. If that happens, check `$this->db->error` or `$stmt->error` respectively.

Comment: in my case it was typo: $stmt->bind_param('ss', $this->username, $this->passowrd); passowrd->password

Answer (score 0):

Your query doesn't use placeholders, you should use

```
$query ="SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '?' AND password = '?'";
```

[example](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#example-1780)